# li hover issue in html page

Tags: html, css

i have a menu its li consist image and text.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><h3><span class="icon-log"></span>Log</h3></a></li>
<ul>
```

my menu lishows like 
[image]

problem is in my hover effect

```
ul li a h3:hover{
 color:#0072c6;
}
ul li .icon-upload:hover{
background:url(/Content/Images/Icons/new-upload-hover.png) no-repeat;
}
```

when i hover on the image , both image and text changed, but when hover on text, image is not changed

Comment: can you please make a fiddle?

Comment: `.icon-upload` should be `icon-log`?

Comment: where is `.icon-upload` in your html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ul li a h3:hover .icon-upload{background:url(/Content/Images/Icons/new-upload-hover.png) no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have use this like this..

```
ul li a h3:hover{
   color:#0072c6;
}
ul li a h3:hover .icon-log{
   background:url(/Content/Images/Icons/new-upload-hover.png) no-repeat;
}
```